# ADODBによるSelect文で行番号も取得したい

Tags: vba

Excel VBAのADODBでSheetの情報をSELECT文で取得しています。

もとのデータは以下の通りです。
[TableA]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[TableB]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そしてコードは以下のとおりです。

```
Dim myCon As Object
    Dim myRS As Object
    Set myCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set myRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


     With myCon
          .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
          .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
          .Open ThisWorkbook.FullName
     End With
     myRS.Open "SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.CountryName FROM ([TableA$A1:C10] AS A LEFT JOIN [TableB$A1:B10] AS B ON A.CountryID = B.CountryID)", myCon, 1, 1
     Dim myVar As Variant
     'myVar = myRS.GetRows
     'myVar = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myVar)
     Worksheets("Result").Cells.Clear
     Worksheets("Result").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset myRS
```

ここでご質問したいことは
実行しているSELECT分の結果にFROM句で指定しているもとのデータの行番号を表示したいです。
以下の結果で「TableAの行番号」、「TableBの行番号」と記載されている列に行番号がほしいです。

どのようにするか、またそもそも実現できるのかご教授ください。
SQL ServerではROW_NUMBER()を使うことができますが、VBAのADODBではどうやるか…

また用途としては、内容に不備があった場合に「どの行」に不備があるかを通知したいためです。
よろしくおねがいします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `ID`や`CountryID`と`行番号`との関係は？ 同一であれば質問文内で表現を統一すべきですし、別物であれば`行番号`を記載すべきです。

Comment: sayuri様、コメントありがとうございます。ID(EmployeeID)やCountryIDと行番号は別物でございます。「行番号を記載すべき」とはJOINする前のもとのSheetのある列に行番号を書いておくべきということでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

SQLの中にTABLE AとBそれぞれサブクエリをかませて仮に行番号用のIDを振る形はいかがでしょうか
AccessなどRow_Number()を使用できないDBでもサブクエリを作成して行番号を取得するためのSQLなどはサンプルが検索できます。
ただ、サブクエリ乱発は可読性は落ちると思います。

自分ならば　一旦　バッファ用のシートにSelect * from で全件出してdictionaryなどで結合すると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。やはり一度バッファ用シートを作成したほうがよさそうですね。そちらで試してみます